# Is Talion still Talion at the end of the game?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, video-games, shadow-of-mordor

In the end of the game,

> we witness Talion express his desire to forge a new Ring of Power.  Does Sauron possess him after the Black Hand is killed?

Answer (score 4):

Yes he is still Talion. Throughout Tolkien lore it is always expressed that power is a never ending search; Talion has a ring maker and what he believes is enough power to make a ring himself, but to do so he would need much more power then he commands to create a ring to rival even that which were given to men, so to attempt something such as this would be fruitless and would just disperse his life force. The evil of Morgoth, which is the desire to pursue goals and power even past what is just, has seemed to seep into Talions heart and is without a doubt going to lead to his downfall; much like Feanor himself. Which would be a prime reason that Warners character doesn't enter into any stories; they could say that the power with which he has become obsessed with (the power to fight Sauron [evil])has corrupted him and driven him into a frenzy in which he will stop at nothing to destroy Sauron, even create a greater evil (another ring), and that this will eventually become his downfall.

For example, Warner could release a DLC in which Talion attempts to create a ring. In this DLC you collect the needed materials and attempt the construction of a ring of power; you succeed. But now, instead of being tethered to the world like Morgoth and to the one ring like Sauron, Talion & Celebrimbor are tethered to THEIR ring, and they no longer have the power to exert their will to control the feeble orc mind. Then, having control of his army once again, Sauron merely sends his 9 wraiths and an army to attack you. You have a ring, they have 9 and an army; you're defeat is inevitable and thus you lose and Talion AND Celebrimbor, having served their purpose, die painfully at the hands of the Sauron (again)

Meaning: Talion is still Talion but the need to dominate has seemed to take control of him, which will inevitably be his downfall; The tragic flaw of many of Tolkiens great heroes.